# mapping the json data taken from the service in the desired format in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, mapping

I have such (dummy) json data:

```
[ {"MAH_ID" : 10, "MAH_AD":"AŞAĞI", "ILCE_ID": 1, "ILCE_AD" : "SARI"}, {"MAH_ID" : 11, "MAH_AD":"YUKARI", "ILCE_ID" : 1, "ILCE_AD" : "SARI"}, {"MAH_ID" : 12, "MAH_AD" :"SAĞ", "ILCE_ID" : 1, "ILCE_AD" : "SARI"}, {"MAH_ID" : 13, "MAH_AD" :"SOL", "ILCE_ID" : 1, "ILCE_AD" : "SARI"}, {"MAH_ID" : 14, "MAH_AD" :"LOW", "ILCE_ID" : 2, "ILCE_AD" : "KIRMIZI"}, {"MAH_ID" : 15, "MAH_AD" :"MİD", "ILCE_ID" : 2, "ILCE_AD" : "KIRMIZI"}, {"MAH_ID" : 16, "MAH_AD" :"HİGH", "ILCE_ID" : 2, "ILCE_AD" : "KIRMIZI"}, {"MAH_ID" : 17, "MAH_AD" :"ULTRAHİGH", "ILCE_ID" : 2, "ILCE_AD" : "KIRMIZI"}, ]
```

From this data;

```
Map<String, List<String>> itemsList = "SARI": [ "AŞAĞI", "YUKARI", "SAĞ", "SOL" ], "KIRMIZI": [ "LOW", "MİD", "HİGH", "ULTRAHİGH" ],
```

I want to access it and show it in my application by doing a map operation. I tried many ways but I couldn't. I would be glad if you help.

Comment: For your json should it be `"MAH_AD" :"AŞAĞI"` instead of `"MAH_AD" ="AŞAĞI"`

Comment: In fact, the data is in the real service, but while I was asking a question, I wrote a service in my head, but the structure is the same, I wonder how I can convert this structure to the map structure I specified.

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply do it by using decoder from dart:convert**

```
 import 'dart:convert';

final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(your_json);
```

Comment: I get an error: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Comment: You have another issue, your json structure is invalid, just check it you will see

Comment: In fact, the data is in the real service, but while I was asking a question, I wrote a service in my head, but the structure is the same, I wonder how I can convert this structure to the map structure I specified.

Comment: If you check your real Json data in some Json converter website you will see that it is invalid